# Can Red Hat 3scale API Management operator be installed in a regular (non-OpenShift) Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, 3scale

Since Red Hat 3scale API Management operator being an open-source project, I was wondering if it can be installed in a regular Kubernetes cluster that is not OpenShift. All the documentation points to ways of installing it in OpenShift. I did notice however that the APICast gateway can be deployed in any Docker/Kubernetes environment. Is it true for the 3scale API Management operator as well?